# Ruby on Rails 3 - What is the better way to create styles, .ccs, layouts for a PC simple app.

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, styles, jrails

I´m new in the developer ambient, but i need to give format, colors, styles, etc, to a web browser simple app for windows. have doubts in certain  aspects like who is the better way? json, jquery, jrails, jquery-ujs.

Any help in this point is appreciated

excuse my english

Comment: Probably sass. Does Windows matter?

Comment: Ambiguous question, what are you asking exactly?  Methodology, tools, platform, approach, samples?

Comment: `json` is a data format and doesn't deal with styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as a beginner on RoR, I really enjoy the Bootstrap framework (css and javascripts). It  provides rapid and nice results, which gives you time for learning and focusing on specific aspects. Bootstrap framework requires jquery: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html

I based my learning on Michael Hartl's tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning

A good advice is not to tightly depend on Bootstrap styles (which may change without notice), but to create your own styles derived from previous ones through mixins: http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html
(But I must admit that I'll care of it only when I feel more comfortable with css).

I hope this helps !

Best regards,

Fred

Comment: thanks man, i really appreciated that information, i am reading the guide.